Measures of the imagine of two close functions
Suppose there are two functions $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ defined on the interval $[0,1]$.  Assume that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ for any $x\in[0,1]$, and $m(f(A))=0$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, $f(A)$ is the imagine of Lebesgue zero set $A$. If $g(A)$ is measurable, can we deduce that $m(g(A))<\epsilon?$

Consider
$$f(x) = \varepsilon \left \lfloor \frac{x}{\varepsilon} \right \rfloor, \qquad
g(x) = x.$$
Then for each $x \in [0, 1]$
$$\left| f(x) - g(x) \right| = \varepsilon \left| \frac{x}{\varepsilon} - \left \lfloor \frac{x}{\varepsilon} \right \rfloor \right| < \varepsilon \cdot 1 = \varepsilon.$$
But $f$ has finite image and $g[ [0, 1] ] = [0, 1]$.

